# How to get data in different Constructors to not always display the same incorrect value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, c++17

I created a solution containing `MainProject` and `CalcProject`.

`MainProject` is a console app that references `CalcProject` and only contains 1 `.cpp` file with the following code:

MainProject.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "Ftr.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace fun::calc;

int main()
//mainFtrTest
{
    std::cout << "Ftr Class Testing Started ! \n\n";

        Ftr c(4);
        std::cout << "Ftr = " << c.getNum() << "\n\n"; 
        
    // Validate Addition operator
        Ftr add1(8);
        Ftr add2(7);
        Ftr total = add1 + add2;
        std::cout << add1.getNum() << " + " << add2.getNum() << " = " << total.getNum() <<"\n\n";
        
        return 0;
}
```

The header file `Ftr.h`

```
#ifndef __FTR_H
#define __FTR_H


#include <cstdint>

namespace fun::calc 
{

    class Ftr
    {
    
    public:

        Ftr() = delete;
        explicit Ftr(double Ftr) noexcept;
        ~Ftr() noexcept;
        Ftr(const Ftr &other) = default;
        Ftr(Ftr &&other) = default;

        double getNum() const noexcept;
        Ftr operator+(const Ftr &rhs) const;
        
        
    private:
        
        double m_Num;
        
    };

}
#endif;
```

The `Ftr.cpp` file

```
#include "Ftr.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fun::calc 

{

// FUNCTION:    Destructor

    Ftr::~Ftr() {
    }

// FUNCTION:    Constructor

    Ftr::Ftr(double Ftr) noexcept {

    }

// FUNCTION:    getNum

    double Ftr::getNum() const noexcept {
        return m_Num;
    }

// FUNCTION:    Overloaded Addition 

    Ftr Ftr::operator+(const Ftr & rhs) const {
        return Ftr(m_Num + rhs.m_Num);
    }

}
```

Here’s a sample of the output that printed

```
Ftr = -9.25596e+61

-9.25596e+61 + -9.25596e+61 = -9.25596e+61
```

I believe that the destructor is automatically executed after each call and therefore the data at the address of the constructors are cleaned every time.

What could possibly cause this erroneous data? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post a [mre] instead of bits and pieces. It's far easier to help when we have something tangible to test. It also goes a long way to narrowing down the problem before even asking.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the minimal info for each of the files.

Comment: Actually - I figured out the issue was that my constructor needed to be initialized to the value being passed in. Thanks anyway

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you could write them as answer and mark them. Because this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor needed to be initialized to the value being passed in.